# Biblatex 2.1 bug

Tags: biblatex, debugging

After updating my texlive 2012 installation using `tlmgr update --all --self` the `biblatex` was updated to version 2.1 and `biber` to version 1.1. Now I cannot compile my document. I get the following error:

```
compiling main.tex...
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:86: Missing number, treated as zero.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:86: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:86: Missing number, treated as zero.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:86: Missing \begin{document}.
main.tex:268: Missing number, treated as zero.
main.tex:268: leading text: \addbibresource
main.tex:268: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. 
main.tex:268: leading text: \addbibresource
main.tex:268: Missing number, treated as zero.
main.tex:268: leading text: \addbibresource
main.tex:268: Missing \begin{document}.
main.tex:268: leading text: \addbibresource
main.tex:704: Missing number, treated as zero.
main.tex:704: leading text: \begin{document}
main.tex:704: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
main.tex:704: leading text: \begin{document}
make: *** [pdf] Error 1
```

With the previous version everything was ok!

Comment: Known, passing, bug in `biblatex` as released to CTAN: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/25. This should be fixed in TeX Live and MiKTeX within a few days.

Comment: You can download from SourceForge and manually install if you need to.

Comment: @Joseph: miktex drags behind currently regarding updates. Its biblatex is still 2.0 and so not affected.